# Why pandas apply() function behvaiour changed in pandas 1.1?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following example,

```
import pandas as pd
def test_func(row):
    row['c'] = str(row['a']) + str(row['b'])
    row['d'] = row['a'] + 1
    return row

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': ['i','j', 'k']})
df.apply(test_func, axis=1)
```

The above code ran on pandas 1.1.0 returns:

```
   a  b   c  d
0  1  i  1i  2
1  1  i  1i  2
2  1  i  1i  2
```

While in pandas 1.0.5 it returns:

```
   a   b    c  d
0  1   i   1i  2
1  2   j   2j  3
2  3   k   3k  4
```

Why did pandas changed the apply() function's behaviour in two versions without updating the documentaion?

Comment: You must messed up somewhere, `1.1.0` gives the second output on my system.

Comment: It was a bug where first row/column was evaluated multiple times and it is listed in Notable bugfixes section: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.1.0.html#apply-and-applymap-on-dataframe-evaluates-first-row-column-only-once

Comment: Tested in pandas `1.1.1` and working well, like second output.

Answer (score 0):

In previous versions the `pd.apply()` will evaluate the first row/column more than once.

While in the v1.1.0 it evaluates the first row/column only once.

It is listed here at [Pandas Doc: Whats New v1.1.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.1.0.html#apply-and-applymap-on-dataframe-evaluates-first-row-column-only-once)

Comment: I verified again, my pandas version is '1.1.0' and this behavior is still there